# how to handle null exception in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

im getting null exception . while im directly exceciting this page. i want to handle null exception

**C#**

```
string json = "";
if (Request.QueryString["data"] !="")
{
    json = Request.QueryString["data"];

    var req = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(json);//getting error in this line
    string requestid = req.requestId;
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYSTRING"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    connection.Open();
}
```

error

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value

Comment: You should handle `DeserializeObject`'s exception as well in case the parameter is not json format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow following two approach:-

**Approach 1:**

```
if (Request.QueryString["data"] != null && Request.QueryString["data"].toString() != string.Empty)
{
   .. Your Content Goes Here
}
```

**Approach 2:**

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["data"].toString()))
{
   .. Your Content Goes Here
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Well presumably `Request.QueryString["data"]` is null. You're currently checking whether it's a reference to an empty string, but not whether it's a null reference. I suspect you want to use [`string.IsNullOrEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty) to check that:

```
string json = Request.QueryString["data"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
{
     var req = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(json);
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting such error when `Request.QueryString["data"]` is null. so you should check for null before using this value. in `c#` null cannot directly converted to String. Better method is suggested by john skeet.

```
 string json=Request.QueryString["data"];
 if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(json)){//Do your code;}
```

Comment: giving error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: `Request.QueryString["data"]` can be `null`

Answer (score 0):

you can u string.isNullOrwhiteSpace() Method and it returns a bool ...true if the input is empty ...false if there is any characters